# expected #status to have initially been "ready_for_publish", but was "ready"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I tried to test some Rails model repeatedly.
But errors like this make me annoying. What should I do for the test?

The Error is below.

```
Failures:

  1) Article Article publish
     Failure/Error: expect{Article.publish(article.id,  1, "some comment")}.to change(article, :status).from(Article.statuses[:ready]).to(Article.statuses[:publish])
       expected #status to have initially been "ready_for_publish", but was "ready"
     # ./spec/models/articles_spec.rb:39:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Here's Factory data.

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :some_article , class: Article do
    current_version 1
    publish_version 1
    thumbnail ""
    status "ready_for_publish"
    publish_datetime "2017/01/01 00:00:00"
    user_id 1
    update_user_id 1
  end
end
```

Model

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord
  enum status: { publish: "publish", reject: "reject", ready: "ready_for_publish", wip: "work_in_progress", scrape: "scrape" }

  def self.publish(id, version, comment)
    article = Article.find(id)
    article_history = ArticleHistory.where(article_id: id, version: version)
    publish_at = article.try(:publish_at) || Time.now.to_s(:db)
    Article.transaction do
      article.update({
        publish_datetime: Time.now.to_s(:db),
        publish_at: publish_at,
        status: Article.statuses[:publish],
        current_version: version,
        publish_version: version
      })

      article_history.update({
        comment: comment
      })
    end
  end
```

Test code

```
RSpec.describe Article, type: :model do
  login_admin

  let(:user) { @admin }
  let(:article) { FactoryGirl.create(:some_article) }
  let(:article_series) { FactoryGirl.create(:article_series) }
  let(:valid_attributes) {
    {
      current_version: 1,
      publish_version: 1,
      thumbnail: "uploads/article/thumb/thumb_20170327055055.png",
      status: "publish",
      publish_datetime: "2017-04-16 19:51:03",
      user_id: user.id,
      update_user_id: user.id,
      article_histories_attributes:[
        version: 1,
  (some code)

  it "Article publish" do
    expect{Article.publish(article.id,  1, "some comment")}.to change(article, :status).from(Article.statuses[:ready]).to(Article.statuses[:publish])
  end
```

I guess `.from(Article.statuses[:ready])` is suspicious, but have no idea to fix it. I'd appreciate if you give some advise.

Answer (score 0):

Updating the record in the database does not actually change the `article` instance which is held in memory in your spec.

```
RSpec.describe Article, type: :model do

  # ...
  describe ".publish" do
    expect do
      Article.publish(article.id,  1, "some comment")
      article.reload!
    end.to change(article, :published?).from(false).to(true)
  end
end
```

Apart from that your code is very quirky. ActiveRecord::Enum's are used to map distinct status to an integer column. Having it map to a slightly different string version of the key is just strange.

```
class Article
  # The enum keys should be adjectives - not verbs
  enum status: [:draft, :ready, :published, :scrapped, :rejected]
end
```

Having a class method called `publish` which takes an instance also seems hacky - `ActiveRecord::Enum` already provides mutating methods:

```
article.published!
article.draft!
```

You can override these or provide you own instance methods to change the status:

```
class Article
  # The enum keys should be adjectives - not verbs
  enum :status, [:draft, :ready, :published, :scrapped, :rejected]

  def publish!
    # ...
  end
end
```

Comment: You can also use gems like [papertrail](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail) instead of creating a version system from scrach.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. As you mentioned above, I didn't know how to use enum.